# error to get backup sql azure from powershell

Tags: sql, powershell, azure

I need create and download backup sql database. I installed Azure powershell. But my script does not work.

```
    $dt = Get-Date -Format yyyyMMddHHmmss
    $dbname = 'AnimalTranslate'
    Backup-SqlDatabase $dbname "C:\drops" "XXX.database.windows.net" "login" "password"
```

I see error:

> Backup-Database : The term 'Backup-Database' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
>   spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

How it's fixed?

Comment: The error says `Backup-Database` but you use `Backup-SqlDatabase`. Do you use that error when using `Backup-SqlDatabase`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `Backup-SqlDatabase` to backup Azure SQL. You need to use one of the methods in this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj650016.aspx